# IIS 7 URL rewrite module equivalent Apache mod_rewritte?

Tags: apache, iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Currently we have an API serving in Apache with Mod Rewrite module with the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,NS]
```

As you can see it obtains the URI segments as they are and calls only index.php which is in charge of exploding all segments '/'.

We are just starting with this new URL Rewrite Module that we downloaded in the IIS official web page.
We have also seen that there are rules within the IIS like Frienly SEO urls and other stuff.

so the question is, How Can I achieve the rules above to work with this IIS module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import it on the IIS server. The IIS server will automatically convert the rewrite rule.

To do this just select your website or the Default Web Site then click on Features View > URL Rewrite > Import Rules (on Action Pane).

Here are some reference to start with:

- [Importing Apache mod_rewrite rules](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules)
- [Converting mod_rewrite rules to IIS7 URL rewrite rules](http://www.robusthaven.com/blog/iis7/converting-mod_rewrite-rules-to-iis7-url-rewrite-rules)
- [IIS7 URL rewrite importing IIS mod_rewrite rules from Apache](https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1487/iis7-url-rewrite-importing-iis-mod-rewrite-rules-apache.aspx)